# После добавления картинки перестаёт генерироваться "R"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-drawable

Собственно, чистый рабочий проект, а сразу после перетаскивания картинки в папку drawable уже не рабочий.

Единственное решение, увиденное мною в видеоуроке, по которому делал, и вообще в сети, - это rebuild project или clean project. Ни то ни другое не помогло.

Вот скрин на всякий: [image: wtf]

Comment: Ошибку внимательно прочитать и всё решится.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 4):

Вам в ошибке чёрным по белому написано, что имя файла-картинки может содержать только `маленькие латинские буквы`, `цифры` и `нижнее подчёркивание`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Англицкий не родной, извиняюсь(

Comment: @ГосподьБомж, он тут у всех неродной) Если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его "верным" нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: ну с нажатием плюсика я сразу же сообразил) Жаль только репутация у меня слишком маленькая(

Comment: @ГосподьБомж, ниже плюсика есть ещё и галочка. На неё репутации у вас хватит)